# How to set equal margins between li elements

Tags: html, css

I want to set equal margins between "Li" elements in the navigation.
right now there is slightly difference between the 
margin left and right as shown in the pic below.

[Here is a fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/aaCY7/196/)

[image: This is the problem:]

Here is the css:

```
.nav {
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 29px;
  line-height: 26px;
  border-top: solid 1px #999;
  border-bottom: solid 2px #333333;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: relative;
  border: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.nav, .nav ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 2.5;
  /* font-size: 13px; */
  z-index: 100;
}

.nav li {
  float: left;
}

.nav a {
  background-color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  z-index: 9999;
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.nav ul a {
  /* border-right: 1px solid #333333; */
  text-indent: 4px;
  padding-left: 4px;
  padding-top: 4px;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
  width: 6.5em;
  line-height: 16pt;
}

.nav > ul > li > a {
  width: 6em;
}
```

Comment: There is no margins between `<li>` elements: https://jsfiddle.net/hashem/aaCY7/197/

Comment: You can remove the widths on your anchors https://jsfiddle.net/aaCY7/198/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the width on your `<a>` elements:

[image: remove these lines]

and add this:

```
.nav li {margin-right: 10px /* or whatever margin you want */}
.nav li:last-child {margin-right: 0}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.nav {
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  border-top: solid 1px #999;
  border-bottom: solid 2px #333333;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.nav, .nav ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 2.5;
  /* font-size: 13px; */
  z-index: 100;
}

.nav li {
    display: inline;
    margin: 0 10px;
}

.nav li a {
  background-color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
```

add the reset of the styling as you wish.
edit: use position and z-index only when it is necessary

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qs3yu7zL/)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time @rkamath it helped but i found easier option as shown below, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding `word-spacing: 5px;` in the nav class:

```
.nav {
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 29px;
  line-height: 26px;
  border-top: solid 1px #999;
  border-bottom: solid 2px #333333;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: relative;
  border: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: normal;
  word-spacing: 5px;
}
```

Hope this helps.